# Is the lyric " Tell them not to fear no more" wrong in expression？

Tags: meaning, grammar

When I listen to Oasis's masterplan and see the lyric 'And as they land upon the shore, tell them not to fear no more', I doubted whether it is wrong in expression.

Usually，If the sentence already has a negative in it for the verb, you cannot use another negative.

So，the lyric should be ‘ Tell them to fear no more’? I'm a lit confused.

Comment: Or tell them not to fear anymore, but neither fits the lyrics. Your assumption is mostly correct, but in some places the ideom of mangled double-negatives is acceptable informally.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your answer.